# React chat application with socket slows down after 15 messages are sent

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, socket.io

I am a newer developer and am trying to make a fairly robust react project, in this project/website there is a page with some custom tabs and one of those tabs is a chat. This chat uses socket to communicate with the server. The problem is that after about 15-20 messages are sent, any clients receiving a chat message will freeze for long periods of time. Here is how I am implementing socket into my react client.

I have a utility file called socket.js:

```
import io from "socket.io-client";
const SOCKET_URL = "http://localhost:3001";
export const socket = io(SOCKET_URL, { transports : ['websocket'] });
```

Inside the react component utilizing socket:

```
import {socket} from "../../utils/socket";

// This code runs (I think) only when the chat state variable changes or when I receive a socket update from the server
useEffect(()=>{
    socket.on("chat msg sent",(chatObj)=>{
        setChat([...chat,chatObj])
    })
},[socket,chat])

// This code is being run when someone sends a chat
const sendChat = (msg) => {
    const socketObj = {name:props.userState.username, content:msg, id,}
    console.log(socketObj);
    socket.emit("sending chat msg",socketObj)
    const clientObj = {name:props.userState.username, content:msg}
    setChat([...chat,clientObj]);
}
```

Here is what this react component is returning:

```
return (
    <div className="container-fluid p-0 m-0 border border-3 border-danger">
        <div className="row p-0 m-0">
            <div className="col-3 border border-primary border-4"><h1></h1></div>
            <div className="col-7 border border-info border-4"></div>
            <div className="col-2 border border-success border-4">
                <div className="tab">
                    <button className="tablinks" onClick={()=>setTab('chat')}>Chat</button>
                    <button className="tablinks" onClick={()=>setTab('characters')}>Char</button>
                    <button className="tablinks" onClick={()=>setTab('compendium')}>Comp</button>
                    <button className="tablinks" onClick={()=>setTab('settings')}>Sett</button>
                </div>
                <div className="tab-content">
                    {tabContent}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <Character/>
    </div>
    );
```

When the chat tab is selected the tabContent state variable is set to this:

```
setTabContent(
    <div>
        <ul className="chat">
            {chat.map((entry)=>{
                return(
                    <li>
                        <h6>{entry.name}</h6>
                        <p>{entry.content}</p>
                    </li>
                )
            })}
        </ul>
        <form onSubmit={(e)=>{
            e.preventDefault();
            sendChat(chatInput);
            setChatInput('');
        }}>
            <input className="" value={chatInput} onChange={(e)=>setChatInput(e.target.value)}/>
        </form>
    </div>
)
```

On the back end I have a file called socketServer.js, and this file contains any of the socket connections, it is just a function that gets exported to the main server file.
socketServer.js:

```
exports = module.exports = function (io) {
    io.on('connection', function (socket) {
        io.emit('greeting', 'welcome to our site!');

        socket.on('join campaign room',(id)=>{
            socket.join(id);
            console.log("joining the campaign room", id);
        });
        
        socket.on('sending chat msg', (socketObj)=>{
            console.log("cool beans", socketObj);
            const chatObj = {name:socketObj.name, content:socketObj.content}
            socket.broadcast.to(socketObj.id).emit('chat msg sent',chatObj);
        });
    });
}
```

Overall this works until too many messages are sent and then it gets very slow for anyone receiving a message. I don't believe that this is a problem with the backend, I think it has to do with react state variables being updated by socket, but I could be wrong.

Comment: If my answer solved your issues @Carsdan Dvorachek, please remember to set it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your useEffect are setting up new connections to socket.io each time you get a new `chat` variable set by `setChat()`. So after 15 messages you have setup 15 listeners to the socket event `sending chat msg`. At the same time you do not remove previous listeners in the cleanup of useEffect.

You could try this and only setup one listener to the socket event

```
import {socket} from "../../utils/socket";

// This code runs (I think) only when the chat state variable changes or when I receive a socket update from the server
useEffect(()=>{
    const setChat = (chatObj) => {
        setChat(oldChat => [...oldChat, chatObj])
    }

    socket.on("chat msg sent", setChat)

    return () => soket.removeListener("chat msg sent", setChat)
},[socket])
```